# Any JavaScript framework supporting all mobile devices platforms 

Tags: javascript-framework

Is there any framework that has support on all mobile platforms? Preferably Windows Mobile, IOS, Blackberry, Android.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in that framework: http://www.phonegap.com/about